# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, web-scraping

I have a python webscraping code which runs very well if I dont insert any result in the database. i.e when i comment out this part of the code

"""
Connecting to Database and putting data into in
"""

```
db= MySQLdb.connect("localhost","XXX","XXX","hmm_Raw_Data")
cursor=db.cursor()


#checking phase to stop scraping


sql = """SELECT Short_link FROM RentalWanted WHERE Short_link=%s"""

rows = cursor.execute(sql,(link_result))

if rows>=1:
    duplicate_count+=1
    print duplicate_count

    # if duplicate_count>=15:
    #   print "The program has started getting duplicates now- The program is terminating"
    #   sys.exit()
else:
    query="""INSERT INTO RentalWanted 
    (Sale_Rent, 
    Type, 
    Area, 
    Nearby, 
    Title,
    Price, 
    PricePerSqrFt, 
    Bedroom,
    Agency_Fee, 
    Bathroom, 
    Size,
    ZonedFor, 
    Freehold, 
    Prop_ref,
    Furnished_status,
    Rent_payment,
    Building_info,
    Amenities,
    Trade_name,
    Licence, 
    RERA_ID,
    Phone_info,
    Short_link) 
    values(
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s,
    %s)"""
    cursor.execute(query,(
    Sale_Rent_result,
    Type_result,
    area_result,
    nearby_result, 
    title_result, 
    price_result, 
    Pricepersq_result, 
    bedroom_result, 
    agencyfee_result, 
    bathroom_result, 
    size_result,
    Zoned_for_result, 
    Freehold_result, 
    propertyref_result, 
    furnished_result, 
    rent_is_paid_result, 
    building_result, 
    Amenities_result, 
    tradename_result, 
    licencenum_result, 
    reraid_result, 
    phone_result, 
    link_result))


db.commit()
cursor.close()
db.close()
```

The error I get when putting the above code is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "RentalWanted.py", line 461, in <module>
    getting_urls_of_all_pages()   File "RentalWanted.py", line 45, in getting_urls_of_all_pages
    every_property_in_a_page_data_extraction(a['href'])    File "RentalWanted.py", line 365, in every_property_in_a_page_data_extraction
    rows = cursor.execute(sql,(link_result))   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 187, in execute
    query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args]) TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I think there is something wrong with the query I am making.

Can anyone help me with figuring out which part needs to be fixed. I have spent hours but have no idea where I am wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really have 23 seperate variables? Better put all into one dictionary, so that it's clearer, what belongs together, and you don't have to count so much. The error is, that execute expects a list as last argument, and `link_result` is probably a string with more than one character, e.g. a list with more than one element:

```
result = {
    "Sale_Rent": Sale_Rent_result,
    "Type": Type_result,
    "Area": area_result,
    "Nearby": nearby_result,
    "Title": title_result,
    "Price": price_result,
    "PricePerSqrFt": Pricepersq_result,
    "Bedroom": bedroom_result,
    "Agency_Fee": agencyfee_result,
    "Bathroom": bathroom_result,
    "Size": size_result,
    "ZonedFor": Zoned_for_result,
    "Freehold": Freehold_result,
    "Prop_ref": propertyref_result,
    "Furnished_status": furnished_result,
    "Rent_payment": rent_is_paid_result,
    "Building_info": building_result,
    "Amenities": Amenities_result,
    "Trade_name": tradename_result,
    "Licence": licencenum_result,
    "RERA_ID": reraid_result,
    "Phone_info": phone_result,
    "Short_link": link_result,
}

db= MySQLdb.connect("localhost","XXX","XXX","hmm_Raw_Data")
cursor=db.cursor()


#checking phase to stop scrapping


sql = """SELECT Short_link FROM RentalWanted WHERE Short_link=%s"""

rows = cursor.execute(sql,(result["Short_link"],))

if rows>=1:
    duplicate_count+=1
    print duplicate_count

    # if duplicate_count>=15:
    #   print "The program has started getting duplicates now- The program is terminating"
    #   sys.exit()
else:
    query = """INSERT INTO RentalWanted ({fields}) VALUES ({values})"""
    query = query.format(fields=','.join(result), values=','.join(['%s']*len(result)))
    cursor.execute(query, result.values())

db.commit()
cursor.close()
db.close()
```

And better make the column `Short_link` unique and catch the error, if you try to insert another row with the same link, instead of checking the constraint by hand:

```
db= MySQLdb.connect("localhost","XXX","XXX","hmm_Raw_Data")
cursor=db.cursor()
try:
    query = """INSERT INTO RentalWanted ({fields}) VALUES ({values})"""
    query = query.format(fields=','.join(result), values=','.join(['%s']*len(result)))
    cursor.execute(query, result.values())
except mysql.connector.IntegrityError:
    duplicate_count+=1
    print duplicate_count
else:
    db.commit()
cursor.close()
db.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I am running the same script on another server and it runs fine. Is it because the python version in the new server is outdated? Old version is Python Python 2.7.3 and new server has Python 2.6.6

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's a backward compatibility issue in MySQL-python version 1.2.5 where it expects a tuple rather than a string when you call execute.

Try this:

```
rows = cursor.execute(sql,( [link_result] ))
```